# Singularity python ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, linux, docker, singularity-container

I am using Singularity to run a Docker Hub container (https://hub.docker.com/r/kavrakilab/dinc-bin), however, I get the following error.

Command:

```
singularity exec docker://kavrakilab/dinc-bin /usr/bin/python /dinc/dinc_job.py -o job-out.log > nohup.out &
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dinc.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-HBcc7g/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "pybel.py", line 89, in <module>
  File "pybel.py", line 68, in _formatstodict
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
[2330128] Failed to execute script dinc
```

Do you have an idea why I get such an error?
Otherwise the program runs well on Docker alone, however I have more aches to computation resource that I would like to utilise.

Server details:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="8 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="8"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 8 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:8"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-8"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="8"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8"
```

Thank you

Samuel

Comment: Please do not link to your code. Post a [mre] instead.

Comment: What is the code for `_formatstodict` then?

Comment: Please check the tags you applied and whether they are justified according to their descriptions. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, shame on you: Just searching here for "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack" turns up 477 questions! I'm halfway sure one of them has an answer explaining your problem.

Comment: I think the problem is how can I run this Docker container on my server environment to take advantage of the compute resources I have. I believe there is a possibility that I need to issue an additional command that prevents python from exiting the container environment.